# override material background color css

Tags: css, material-ui

Hello there i am trying to override a material background color i have try different ways still cant make it change

using the inspector on the web browser found the css that holds what i want to change

```
.form-control-wrapper .material-input::before {
position: absolute;
content: "";
width: 100%;
left: 0;
height: 2px;
background-color: #009587;
bottom: -1px;
-webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
-ms-transform: scaleX(0);
transform: scaleX(0);
transition: -webkit-transform 0s;
transition: transform 0s;}
```

I have try to change this code but the material color persist, any ideas?
Thanks

Adding more content

`<span class="material-input"></span>`

this has inside a before and after event the before part holds the background color.

this is the html calling the css material:

```
<div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span id="icon" class="mdi mdi-social-person"></span></span>
                                        <input name="message" id="message" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose an username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" maxlength="768">
                                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button id="send" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat">Connect</button>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: try using "!important" like so: background-color: #009587 !important;

Comment: can  i know for which html this class is used, if i get more detials about this i can help you well

Comment: what have you tried exactly? as long as your CSS is declared after the Material CSS and has enough specificity to override it you should be able to get your style applied without using `!important`... Also it would help if you share the HTML for this input so people can test it out

Comment: I was not able to replicate the issue with your code; please consider adding a snippet that shows the input as you have it

Answer (score 0):

Try using the markup **!important**:

```
.form-control-wrapper .material-input::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #009587 !important;
    bottom: -1px;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: -webkit-transform 0s;
    transition: transform 0s;
}
```

It forces this property over all the others set

Comment: thanks for your quick reply yes i have tried the important to override the material color

Answer (score 0):

Don't listen to the comment above. Using !important isn't the best practice.
To override material styles which are not visible/used in html you should use ::ng-deep pseudo-class selector and it's better to use it with :host selector.

```
:host {
    ::ng-deep {
        .form-control-wrapper .material-input::before {
            background-color: #009587;
        }
    }
}
```